# Is there a way to get raw geojson data and smooth it, and have a new smoothed file?

Tags: geojson

I am working with a large number of geojson data, is there a way to smooth raw geojson data to create a new file of geojson data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you define what you mean by "smooth"? What data are you trying to manipulate? Is your goal to make the polygons appear rounded instead of having sharp corners? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There are various online resources for this, one of my favourites is www.mapshaper.org.

This will allow you to smooth out the boundaries and as such, create a smaller file.

Drag the file into the drop area, then click 'Simplify' in the top right hand corner after the file has been rendered.

Hope this helps.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is nice implementation of Chaikin's smoothing algorithm in [javascript to smooth a path](https://github.com/Jam3/chaikin-smooth).